# Is there a bit-wise trick for checking the divisibility of a number by 2 or 3?

Tags: java, python, c++, c, bit-manipulation

I am looking for a bit-wise test equivalent to `(num%2) == 0 || (num%3) == 0`.

I can replace `num%2` with `num&1`, but I'm still stuck with `num%3` and with the logical-or.

This expression is also equivalent to `(num%2)*(num%3) == 0`, but I'm not sure how that helps.

Comment: I think: for 3, the code can check &0x03, &0x06, &0x09, &0x0C, &0x0F  which should catch all values that are evenly divisible by 3

Comment: @user3629249 What about 0x12?

Comment: Note that modulo operations with constant divisors can be implemented very efficiently, and commonly used compilers already incorporate these efficient methods. The generated code may be a bit faster if `num` is an unsigned integer type. You may wish to check the disassembly of the binary executable (e.g. via `objdump`) to confirm. You may also want to look into using a logical-or `|` instead of a boolean-or `||` if speed is the objective.

Comment: @njuffa: Yep, I see the `((num%2)|(num%3)) == 0` option now. Good idea, thanks (mind if I edit that into the question?). As to the other suggestion, I can look directly into the dis-assembly while debugging the code, but I am looking for something that will work **regardless** of the underlying architecture (compiler + HW). Of course, some DSPs may support this on the HW level (hence, so will the compiler provided along with them), but it is a platform-dependent solution. I am looking for an agnostic (cross-platform) solution.

Comment: @njuffa most compilers use the good old "division by a constant" trick, then multiply back and compare whether the number is the same as before. It's faster than using an actual division for sure, but I've never seen a compiler do it properly yet. I've tried it on GCC, Clang and ICC.

Comment: @barakmanos: Sure, edit as you see fit. The optimal implementation will be architecture dependent at least for `%3`. If the hardware has a fast integer multiplier, a multiplication-based method will be best. The compiler for a given platform should already incorporate the most advantageous method for that platform, and allows programmers to use the most readable method at source level.

Comment: @njuffa: I'm aware of the fact that any decent compiler would probably replace `num%2` with `num&1` (wasn't aware of the `num%3` replacement though). In general, I assume that on **every** platform: 1. Any bit-wise operation is equal to or better than any arithmetic or logical operation. 2. Any arithmetic operation is equal to or better than division and modulo operations. Other than that, I believe that the "efficiency rate" varies among different architectures.

Comment: @njuffa: In any case, I have not mentioned which operations are "better than" others because I knew that it would shift the focus away from the question at hand. That's one of the reasons why I tagged it with Java and Python, although the question itself is pretty language-agnostic (the other reason is that I wanted to use a few pieces of code within the question, so I had to tag it with some appropriate languages. But my point in this question was to keep the focus on a programmatic solution, rather than "diving into a HW debate". Thank you very much.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, though it's not very pretty, you can do something analogous to the old "sum all the decimal digits until you have only one left" trick to test if a number is divisible by 9, except in binary and with divisibility by 3. You can use the same principle for other numbers as well, but many combinations of base/divisor introduce annoying scaling factors so you're not just summing digits anymore.

Anyway, 16<sup>n</sup>-1 is divisible by 3, so you can use radix 16, that is, sum the nibbles. Then you're left with one nibble (well, 5 bits really), and you can just look that up. So for example in C# (slightly tested) edit: brute-force tested, definitely works

```
static bool IsMultipleOf3(uint x)
{
    const uint lookuptable = 0x49249249;
    uint t = (x & 0x0F0F0F0F) + ((x & 0xF0F0F0F0) >> 4);
    t = (t & 0x00FF00FF) + ((t & 0xFF00FF00) >> 8);
    t = (t & 0x000000FF) + ((t & 0x00FF0000) >> 16);
    t = (t & 0xF) + ((t & 0xF0) >> 4);
    return ((lookuptable >> (int)t) & 1) != 0;
}
```

---

The trick from my comment, `x * 0xaaaaaaab <= 0x55555555`, works through a modular multiplicative inverse trick. 0xaaaaaaab * 3 = 1 mod 2<sup>32</sup>, which means that `0xaaaaaaab * x = x / 3` if and only if
`x % 3 = 0`. "if" because `0xaaaaaaab * 3 * y = y` (because `1 * y = y`), so if `x` is of the form
`3 * y` then it will map back to `y`. "only if" because no two inputs are mapped to the same output, so everything not divisible by 3 will map to something higher than the highest thing you can get by dividing anything by 3 (which is `0xFFFFFFFF / 3 = 0x55555555`).

You can read more about this (including the more general form, which includes a rotation) in [Division by Invariant Integers using Multiplication (T. Granlund and P. L. Montgomery)](https://gmplib.org/~tege/divcnst-pldi94.pdf).

You compiler may not know this trick. For example this:

```
uint32_t foo(uint32_t x)
{
    return x % 3 == 0;
}
```

Becomes, on Clang 3.4.1 for x64,

```
movl    %edi, %eax
movl    $2863311531, %ecx       # imm = 0xAAAAAAAB
imulq   %rax, %rcx
shrq    $33, %rcx
leal    (%rcx,%rcx,2), %eax
cmpl    %eax, %edi
sete    %al
movzbl  %al, %eax
ret
```

G++ 4.8:

```
mov eax, edi
mov edx, -1431655765
mul edx
shr edx
lea eax, [rdx+rdx*2]
cmp edi, eax
sete    al
movzx   eax, al
ret
```

What it should be:

```
imul eax, edi, 0xaaaaaaab
cmp eax, 0x55555555
setbe al
movzx eax, al
ret
```

Comment: Yep, not very pretty indeed. I will run some tests on it. Thanks :)

Comment: @barakmanos you can do something much prettier with a multiplication, a rotate (actually no rotate in this case, but in general there may be one), and a comparison - but that's not bitwise. Are you interested in it anyway?

Comment: As long as it doesn't contain a loop - yes (I did not write it in the question in order to keep it clear and simple). Thanks.

Comment: Does that catch both 2 and 3, or just 3? Also, are you sure that there is nothing that in "some way" catches any number whose GCD with 6 is greater than 1?

Comment: Well that's just for divisibility by 3, I'm not sure how to combine them in one thing, will think about it

Comment: Can you explain the `x * 0xaaaaaaab <= 0x55555555` expression though? It may overflow, so obviously there's a "bit trick" here that works regardless of the actual outcome of the multiplication. Thanks.

Comment: BTW, if that really works for 3, then you might as well use it instead of that original ("non-pretty") suggestion of yours, right?

Comment: @barakmanos well sure but you asked for bitwise, so that's what you got :)

Comment: Ooops... That's right, my apologies. So it's not much different than `(x%3) != 0`, except perhaps on some DSPs where division and modulo operations are "costly", but not in the general case.

Answer (score 6):

I guess I'm a bit late to this party, but here's a slightly faster (and slightly prettier) solution than the one from harold:

```
bool is_multiple_of_3(std::uint32_t i)
{
    i = (i & 0x0000FFFF) + (i >> 16);
    i = (i & 0x00FF) + (i >> 8);
    i = (i & 0x0F) + (i >> 4);
    i = (i & 0x3) + (i >> 2);
    const std::uint32_t lookuptable = 0x49249249;
    return ((lookuptable >> i) & 1) != 0;
}
```

It's C++11, but that doesn't really matter for this piece of code. It's also brute-force tested for 32-bit unsigned ints. It saves you at least one bit-fiddling op for each of the first four steps. It also scales beautifully to 64 bits - only one additional step needed at the beginning.

The last two lines are obviously and shamelessly taken from harold's solution (nice one, I wouldn't have done that so elegantly).

Possible further optimizations:

- The `&` ops in the first two steps will be optimized away by just using the lower-half registers on architectures that have them (x86, for example).
- The largest possible output from the third step is `60`, and from the fourth step it's `15` (when the function argument is `0xFFFFFFFF`). Given that, we can eliminate the fourth step, use a 64-bit `lookuptable` and shift directly into that following the third step. This turns out to be a bad idea for Visual C++ 2013 in 32-bit mode, as the right shift turns into a non-inline call to code that does a lot of tests and jumps. However, it should be a good idea if 64-bit registers are natively available.
- The point above needs to be reevaluated if the function is modified to take a 64-bit argument. The maximum outputs from the last two steps (which will be steps 4 and 5 after adding one step at the beginning) will be `75` and `21` respectively, which means we can no longer eliminate the last step.

---

The first four steps are based on the fact that a 32-bit number can be written as

```
(high 16 bits) * 65536 + (low 16 bits) = 
(high 16 bits) * 65535 + (high 16 bits) + (low 16 bits) = 
(high 16 bits) * 21845 * 3 + ((high 16 bits) + (low 16 bits))
```

So the whole thing is divisible by 3 if and only if the right parenthesis is divisible by 3. And so on, as this holds for `256 = 85 * 3 + 1`, `16 = 5 * 3 + 1`, and `4 = 3 + 1`. (Of course, this is generally true for even powers of two; odd powers are one less than the nearest multiple of 3.)

The numbers that are input into the following steps will be larger than 16-bit, 8-bit, and 4-bit respectively in some cases, but that's not a problem, as we're not dropping any high-order bits when shifting right.