# Efficient mod 3 in x86 assembly

Tags: assembly, x86-64, micro-optimization

The `DIV` instruction is expensive on modern processors. Is there a faster way to reduce a 64-bit integer mod 3 in x86 assembly?

Comment: If you're going to use this only to test whether the result is zero or not, there is a much simpler way to test for divisibility than actually computing the remainder.

Comment: Strongly related: [How does the GCC implementation of module (%) work, and why does it not use the div instruction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4361979/how-does-the-gcc-implementation-of-module-work-and-why-does-it-not-use-the)

Comment: For the divisibility check mentioned by @harold, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27847160/780717)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are algorithms for that, based on performing division by multiplication with the reciprocal of the divisor. There are various papers on this, the one most commonly cited is:

Torbjörn Granlund and Peter L. Montgomery. "Division by invariant integers using multiplication." *ACM SIGPLAN Notices*. Vol. 29, No. 6, August 1994, pp. 61-72 [(online)](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/9003/554841903f62440806d8e4477401b448e042.pdf)

Your C/C++ compiler very likely already uses a variant of this algorithm when optimizations are turned on. For example, my Intel compiler, version 13, turns this:

```
#include <stdint.h>
uint64_t mod3 (uint64_t a)
{
    return a % 3;
}
```

into this (line-end annotations mine):

```
mod3    PROC
; parameter 1: rcx
        mov       r8, 0aaaaaaaaaaaaaaabH      ;; (scaled) reciprocal of 3
        mov       rax, rcx
        mul       r8                          ;; multiply with reciprocal
        shr       rdx, 1                      ;; quotient
        lea       r9, QWORD PTR [rdx+rdx*2]   ;; back multiply with 3
        neg       r9
        add       rcx, r9                     ;; subtract from dividend 
        mov       rax, rcx                    ;; remainder
        ret
mod3    ENDP
```

Comment: There's also: Niels Möller and Torbjörn Granlund. ["Improved division by invariant integers."](https://gmplib.org/~tege/division-paper.pdf), which is better suited to modern processors. But probably not as efficient for this special case.

Comment: Indeed, all x86-64 compilers that I've seen apply this algorithm, generating almost identical code. The only difference is that Intel tends to do `neg`+`add`, instead of `sub`. I've never figured out a good reason for that; their documentation doesn't indicate that `add` is any faster than `sub`. So either this is just a quirk of the compiler's internal implementation, or they have some interesting inside information on their own processors that says different.

Comment: Impressive that's actually faster.

Comment: @Joshua 64bit division is pretty slow. Even on something new like Kaby calculating 0/3 with a 64bit div takes over 30 cycles and that's the *best* case, it goes up to nearly 50 cycles for higher dividends (or nearly 100 when considering all possible dividends/divisors).